# Converting .HEIC to JPEG using imagick in C#

Tags: c#, imagick, imagemagick.net

I'm having trouble in converting heic file to jpeg

I have already tried searching it online, i can find how to write to a folder but not how to get a byte[] of a converted file so that i can save it

```
       byte[] file = null;
        file = Convert.FromBase64String(dto.File);

        //Convert HEIC/HEIF to JPF
        if (extension == "HEIC" || extension == "HEIF")
        {
          try
          {
           using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
              images.Read(file);
              using (IMagickImage vertical = images.AppendVertically())
              {
                var imgname = filename + ".jpeg";
                vertical.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
                vertical.Density = new Density(300);
                vertical.Write(imgname);
                extension = "jpeg";
            }
            }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
          }
        }
            documentId = Service.AddSupportingDocument(file, extension , userName);
```

I'm not able to get the output file, it's just a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, and just like @SLaks suggested, you need to do it via a MemoryStream. Check this [example](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/ConvertImage.md#convert-image-from-one-format-to-another) straight from the docs:

```
// Read first frame of gif image
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("Snakeware.gif"))
{
    // Save frame as jpg
    image.Write("Snakeware.jpg");
}

// Write to stream
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
// Tells the xc: reader the image to create should be 800x600
settings.Width = 800;
settings.Height = 600;

using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Create image that is completely purple and 800x600
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("xc:purple", settings))
    {
        // Sets the output format to png
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
        // Write the image to the memorystream
        image.Write(memStream);
    }
}

// Read image from file
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("Snakeware.png"))
{
    // Sets the output format to jpeg
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
    // Create byte array that contains a jpeg file
    byte[] data = image.ToByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Other solution.

Works with **dotnet 6** & **Nuget Package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU**

```
using ImageMagick;

string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"__PATH__", "*.heic", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in allfiles)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info.FullName))
    {
        // Save frame as jpg
        image.Write(@$"__OUTPATH__{info.Name}.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting, by implication, that e.g. the accepted answer does _not_ work with .NET 6 or `Magick.NET-Q16`?

Comment: no, but it's the easiest path I've found with . NET6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `MemoryStream`, call `.Write()` to write the image to the memory stream, then call `.ToArray()` on the stream to get the bytes it wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using **dotnet 6** & **Nuget Package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU**

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
    // Save frame as jpg
    image.Write(filePath2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer by @Sios, I tested the code using tasks and with many images the code gets them converted 4 times faster using 100% of the PC resources (it always depends on your hardware).
Here is the updated code:

```
using ImageMagick;
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

var inputPath = "D:\\Wallpapers";
var outputPath = "D:\\Wallpapers\\PNG_Test2";
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(inputPath, "*.heic", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var tasks = new List<Task>();


foreach (var file in allfiles)
{

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info.FullName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: " + info.FullName);
            image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpg;
            image.Write(Path.Join(outputPath, info.Name + ".Jpg"));
            Console.WriteLine("Processed: " + info.FullName);
        }
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds / 10);

Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```